# Parameter passed through activities is not displayed as a TextView

Tags: android, textview

in my app the user enters his username in signup activity and when he clicks the submit button, his username should be displayed in a TextView in the newprofile activity. My problem is that the TextView is not displayed.

My NewProfile.class code:

```
package dmst.allamoda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class NewProfile extends ActionBarActivity {

public static String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newprofile);
    Button btnSimple1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
    btnSimple1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), Home3.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
    Button btnSimple2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile);
    btnSimple2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });

    Button btnSimple3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.friends);
    btnSimple3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent3 = new Intent(v.getContext(), Friends2.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
        }
    });

    Button btnSimple4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    btnSimple4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent4 = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case (1) : {
            if (resultCode == NewProfile.RESULT_OK) {
                String newText = data.getStringExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
                textView.setTextSize(40);
                textView.setText(newText);
                setContentView(textView);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the TextView in my activity_newprofile.xml

```
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:gravity="top"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have Username from the SignUpActivity.java, you'll need to pass that information to the NewProfile activity using Intent Extra to display it.  Here's how

In your SignupActivity, when calling NewProfile activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, NewProfileActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("username", the username that user entered);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your NewProfileActivity, you could get/set the username

```
// get the username
final String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

// set the username
yourTextView.setText(username);
```

Comment: Here is the code from Signup.class 
            `Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewProfile.class);
    intent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER,
    username.getText().toString());
     startActivity(intent);`
Do you mean that I don't need the onActivityResult method in  NewProfile.class ?

Comment: correct, you don't need onActivityResult() in your NewProfileActivity.  You can just get the userName by final String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);

Comment: great, if that is the correct answer, please accept and upvote so other could refer to it when needed. thanks